# Sudo command does not respond in terminal on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sudo

I am trying  to run any command using `sudo`, but the cursor just blinks when pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and nothing happens. Then:

```
sem@sem:~$ sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo: unable to resolve host sem
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!